# Issue while using bootstrap-tagsinput api angularjs support

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to integrate bootstrap-tagsinput plugin for angularjs support from below link

```
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
```

But, when I am adding this to my HTML file after adding bootsrap-taginput.css and bootsrap-taginput.js and bootsrap-taginput-angular.css.

bootsrap tag is not identified as HTML tag and hence it doesnt get rendered on my page. May I know what could be the issue for this? Its purely basics but since I am not a UI guy, i have least idea about consistencies across versions. If someone can tell me what is the issue because I feel atleast bootsrap-tagsinput tag should be rendered, which its not!

```
<bootstrap-tagsinput
ng-model="cities"
typeahead-source="queryCities"
tagclass="getTagClass"
itemvalue="value"
 itemtext="text">
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try Add a closing tag, like this:

```
    <bootstrap-tagsinput
      ng-model="cities"
      typeahead-source="queryCities"
      tagclass="getTagClass"
      itemvalue="value"
      itemtext="text"></<bootstrap-tagsinput>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a implementation of a simple directive for bootstrap-tagsinput, I have implemented very simple directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yourApp')
.directive('tagsInputEditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            options: '@', //receive all the options in a JSON array - one-way binding
            selection: '='//two-way binding - the selected tags to use
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<input id="inputCategories" type="text" data-role="tagsinput"/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var el = $(element);
            var options = JSON.parse(scope.options);

            //select initial values for typeahead:
            el.val(function () {
                return cat.allCategories.map(function (category) {
                    return category.Tag;//the object used has a Tag property
                });
            });

            //configuration of typeahead options    
            el.tagsinput({
                typeahead: {
                    source: options.map(function (option) {
                        return option.Tag;
                    })
                },
                freeInput: true
            });

            //event handlers to sync data
            el.on('itemAdded', syncItems);
            el.on('itemRemoved', syncItems);

            function syncItems() {
                var items = el.val().split(',');

                //clear all items and store the new items selection
                scope.selection.length = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    scope.selection.push(items[i]);
                }

                //you should tell angular to refresh the scope and send data back to the scope    
                scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The usage is like this:

```
<tags-input-editor options="{{model.categories}}" selection="model.selectedCategories" />
```

You see, the controller defines the model with the categories and selected categories. This is sufficient for me by now. I'm not using other features of the component but from here is very easy to continue - I use traditional jQuery code inside the directive and the documentation of the component seems to be sufficient.